# Jackson serialize object into String

Tags: java, json, spring

I have the following class structure:

```
class A {
    B objB;
    int val;
    ...
}

class B {
    int val2;
}
```

Now, my current understanding is that JSON created for an object of `class A` with Jackson would look like this:

```
{
    "val":10,
    "objB":
    {
        "val2":20
    }
}
```

What I'm trying to achieve is a JSON that looks like this:

```
{
    "val":10,
    "objB":"MY_STRING"
}
```

This value of `MY_STRING` is computed based on the value of the integer `val2`. Is there a way I can achieve this in Jackson??

I see that I can create a custom serializer as suggested in https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-custom-serialization
I can specify the custom serializer on `Class A` and write code that would serialize all the member variables in `Class A`, but that would require changing the serializer for `A` everytime I add/remove a member from `Class A`.

Is there a way that I can specify this custom serializer of `class B` and achieve the same result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`@JsonValue`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.8/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonValue.html) could help:

```java
class B {

  int val2;

  @JsonValue
  public String serialise() {
    return "foo:" + val2;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Also `@JsonProperty`or even better `@JsonGetter` can do that. You can annotate some other methd instead of `getVal2()` as Json getter for that property. And that would do the trick. Read about it here: [Jackson Annotation Examples](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-annotations)